# how to run ruby syntax in a regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

ok so assume I have a variable that will be changing in every controller. @keyword and I am trying to find out if a specified keyword is in a post. My code is

```
= if posting.body =~ /<%= @keyword %>/
   then post //pseudocode here not my actual code. this isn't needed
```

I tried using `.html_safe` (I am using haml btw) and .raw(i wouldn't normally do this, but was suggested on another forum question that I didn't write. I only want to pass that instance variable from the controller. I don't think this would be hard, but I know there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= if posting.body =~ /#{@keyword}/
```

Try this and see if it works. I think this is how ruby is interpolated inside a regex.

Answer (score 1):

The `=~` operator matches the regular expression against a string, and it returns either the offset of the match from the string if it is found, otherwise nil.

See [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) for the documentation.

If you are looking keyword in REGEX then your syntax will be:

```
posting.body =~ /^#{URI::regexp}$/
```

For variable:

```
posting.body =~ /^#{@keyword}$/
```

Comment: This way didn't work because of the caret and dollarsign. It could be just based on what I'm doing with my application though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
= if posting.body =~ /#{@keyword}/
  then post
```

The `<%= something %>` in template is used to output some data to the response body. I believe that the code after `=` is just normal Ruby code.

BTW, you may need to escape the `@keyword` content, in case that it contains some special characters used in regular expression (`.` for example).

```
= if posting.body =~ /#{Regexp.escape(@keyword)}/
  then post
```